# Telerik RadEditor: Word Content in Clipboard Interception

Tags: radeditor

When the user copies/pastes from Word using ctrl+v into the RadEditor control, I do not want the dialog for cleaning Word markup and want to default the option systematically to Ok. Is there a way to do this? I have not found any documentation stating how to remove the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set the RadEditor StripFormattingOptions property to MSWord. You can find more information in this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/cleaningwordformatting/defaultcs.aspx.

Rumen